# How to login to multiple work accounts to Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am using mac and windows both operating systems. I installed Microsoft Teams for Work and wanted to log in with multiple accounts into the same desktop app.

I wanted to log in to multiple organizations having different credentials.

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings -> Account -> Add account?

Comment: Yes it only allows adding of one work/school account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Teams app provides facility to login into the multiple accounts. Refer below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For now, you can't add multiple work accounts. There is a request made for it:  [Enable usage of multiple Teams accounts at the same time](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/c9995dc8-811a-ed11-b83e-000d3a4d9c20). There is no mention yet when the feature is expected to become available. According to the Microsoft representative on that page:

> Support for multiple accounts is a top priority. We are actively working on it and look forward to providing an update on timing.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, it hasn't been implemented (for several years already).

However, there is a workaround (for Windows users). I saw it somewhere on StackOverflow I think, but can't find the original answer now.

Short story: you need to run teams app under a different user.

Long story:

1. Create a new user in your system (no need for a Microsoft login, just local user is fine)
2. Log in under this user. Run Teams and log in under the account you require.
3. Log out from this user, log in under your main user.
4. Go to the C:\Users[account_that_you_created_for_teams]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams. Here you need either allow yourself to access the folder or while in step 2 - add access for your main user.
5. Create a link to the update.exe file. Open this link and change it to

   C:\Users[account_that_you_created_for_teams]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"
6. Move it to your desktop
7. Press Shift and right click on the link. Find 'Run as different user'. When asked - enter credentials of a user that you have created at step 1.

That's it. Now you have 2 apps with different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, which your main organization account I suggest you to use the official Microsoft Teams(for the best experience), and any other secondary(and beyond) organizations/personals Teams you will have another Teams app created/running in the official MicrosoftEdge this way:
.

1. Download/Install/Open Microsoft Edge for your operation system(MacOS in this example)
2. Click on the Avatar next to the address bar, and click on Add to login with your account
   [image]
3. Open Microsoft Teams in the browser [ HTTPS://TEAMS.MICROSOFT.COM ]
4. Once logged in click on the Settings and more option in the browser top bar
5. From the menu select [Apps] and then [Install this site as an app]
   [image]
   [Extra] I highly suggest you set this another teams app to start with your Mac(if it's also an professional/enterprise account), which you can do this way:
6. Open the Apple menu at the top-left corner of your screen, Select System Settings, and then Click General -> Login Items.
   [image]
7. Drag and drop the new Teams app to the "Login Items" list
   [image]
8. And you are done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

multiple accounts, e.g. more than two accounts are possible on WIN OS, IOS but apparently not under the MAC OS teams app. the subtle way of MSO to push you towards using their handicapped OS :-P

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).